# Problems with work on an inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, free-body-diagram

> A constant force $F_a$ of magnitude $82.0N$ is applied to a $3.00 kg$ shoe box at angle $53.0^{\circ}$, causing the box to move up a frictionless ramp at constant speed. How much work is done on the box by $F$ when the box has moved a through vertical distance $h = 0.150 m$?

[image]

Without writing the full solution provided by my lecturer, why is the work only calculated by the product of $F_{gravity}$ and the vertical distance of $0.150m$?

$i.e.$ $W = mgdcos\theta = -(3.00kg\times9.81m/s^2 \times 0.15m) = -4.41J$

Why isn't the vertical component of $F_a$ and the normal force, $F_N$ considered as well?

$i.e.$ W = $(F_{N, vertical}-(F_acos\phi + mg))dcos\theta$

Comment: Please see [our guide](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) on writing good titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem needs to take into account the fact that the ramp is frictionless, and the mass is moving at constant speed.  None of the solutions presented so far have taken this into account.  If $\theta$ is the angle that the ramp makes with the horizontal, the component of F along the ramp is $F(\sin53\cos\theta+\cos53\sin\theta)$.  If the box is moving at constant speed, the net force on the box in the direction tangent to the ramp must be zero.  So,
$$F(\sin53\cos\theta+\cos53\sin\theta)=mg\sin\theta$$From this equation it follows that $$\cot\theta=\frac{mg-F\cos53}{F\sin53}\tag{1}$$

The vertical component of the force F is $F\cos53$, and the vertical displacement is h.

The horizontal component of the force F is $F\sin53$, and the horizontal displacement is $h\cot\theta$

So the work done by the force F on the box is:
$$W=hF\cos53+hF\sin53\cot\theta\tag{2}$$
If we combine Eqns. 1 and 2, we obtain the work done by the force F as simply:
$$W=mgh\cos53\tag{3}$$The key to solving this problem correctly is to take into account the fact that the ramp is frictionless and the velocity of the box on the ramp is constant.

Comment: Thanks for that Chester. So in essence you could say that that horizontal forces cancel each other out? Hence, when an object moves up an inclined plane with some applied force $F_a$, the net work is simply, $mg\Delta ycos\theta$.

Comment: If it asks for the vertical work only that is

Comment: I don't see how the horizontal forces cancelling each other has anything to do with how much work the force F does on the box horizontally.  We already see in Eqn. 2 that the horizontal component of F does do work on the box, and, from Eqns. 1 and 2,  the vertical work that the force F does on the box is **not** $mgh\cos53$.  So, if you're looking for a simple interpretation of what's happening, I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, work is calculated by force product distance that parallel to force. So the work that you want calculates below:$$W=\left(F_a\sin (\phi-53)-mg\sin 53\right)\frac{h}{\sin 53}$$

Comment: What quantity does $mgsin53$ yield? LIkewise with $F_asin(\phi-53)$?

Comment: Because $\phi$ is $53^{\circ}$

Comment: If ∅=53°, then your force F_a doesn’t do work and the box doesn’t move up.

Comment: But for $d=\frac{h}{sin53}$, the angle of inclination  would have to $53^{\circ}$, wouldn't it? But here, the angle the force is applied at is $53^{\circ}$ to the vertical axis.